# UIViewController handling only sharing features

Tags: ios, share, viewcontroller

I have a bunch of apps that intensively share data to social networks, email, etc. I have to check also if user's device is running iOS 5 or 6 in order to present either UIActivityViewController or an UIActionSheet, etc.

I would like to take off all this functionality of my View Controllers and put the code in a class that I could call doing something like this : [ShareManager share:userInfo]   This "ShareManager" class should then present the right set of options to the user and perform the corresponding action. The problem is that most of the sharing is done presenting Modal View Controllers, thus "ShareManager" should be a ViewController, right? 
Which would be the right approach? a View Controller without a view? some pattern? no take out the code at all?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a couple of projects by myself:

https://github.com/jmacmullin/BCDShareSheet

https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare

Both uses a shared instance (inherits NSObject) to do the work.

Any other ideas are welcome